Next.js sending a response object/body with revalidating path from Server Action
Is it possible to send a response body/object when also revalidating a path inside Server Action in Next.js?
This is my Server Action function:
app/_actions/todo.tsx, addTodo server action:
export async function addTodo(prevState: any, formData: FormData) {
    const errors: {
        title?: string;
        description?: string;
    } = {};
    const title = formData.get('title')?.toString();
    const description = formData.get('description')?.toString();
    
    // Validate title and description

    if(errors.title || errors.description) {
        return { errors };
    }
    
    await dbConnect();

    const todo = new Todo({
        title,
        description
    });

    await todo.save();

    revalidatePath('/');

    return { todo: { title, description } };
}

Sometimes my formState object which is returned by useFormState hook has todo property after processing the request successfully and sometimes it doesn't.
So it doesn't seem to be working reliably.
Update
I figured out that what was breaking the cache invlidation behaviour in my app is usage of loading.tsx file in root app directory. I want to show a "Loading..." text while the todo list on path / is being loaded, so I want to keep it this way but the revalidatePath and returning a response body in the server action works only when I remove app/loading.tsx file. Any help is appreciated!
This is the file structure of app folder:


app/page.tsx:

import { Metadata } from 'next';
import TodoList from './_components/Todos/TodoList';

export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: 'Todo App',
    description: 'Todo application for practicing Next.js',
};

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <TodoList />
    );
}


app/loading.tsx:

export default function Loading() {
    return <p className="text-yellow-400">Loading...</p>;
}


app/_components/Todos/TodoList.tsx:

'use server';
import { fetchTodos } from '@/app/_actions/todos';
import TodoListItem from './TodoListItem';

export default async function TodoList() {
    const fetchedTodos = await fetchTodos();

    if (!fetchedTodos.length) {
        return <p className="text-red-500">No todos were found!</p>;
    }

    return (
        <ul>
            {fetchedTodos.map((todo) => (
                <TodoListItem key={todo._id.toString()} todo={todo} />
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
}


app/_actions/todos.tsx, fetchTodos server action:

export async function fetchTodos() {
    await dbConnect();

    const todos = await Todo.find().sort({ createdAt: 'desc' });

    return todos;
}

Github respository for the project:
https://github.com/caglartufan/next-todo

the issue is you have _loading.tsx file. Its name should be loading.tsx. if you read docs

The special file loading.js helps you create meaningful Loading UI
with React Suspense

If you add console.log('loading'); to Loadin component, you will see the log statement on server terminal:

here is the laoding on ui:

to see this you have to change the network load to Slow 3G
success message also shows:


Thank you for the answer. I think I caused a confusion in my question. I intentionally renamed loading.tsx file to _loading.tsx to set it inactive since it breaks the revalidation process. If you rename it back to loading.tsx and run the application, you will probably see that after adding a new todo, revalidation doesn't work and even the success message above the new todo form is not visible because it also prevents that for some reason.

success message also get displayed

what about wrapping the component with Suspense? You can pass your loading component through the fallback function of Suspense.
import { Metadata } from 'next';
import TodoList from './_components/Todos/TodoList';

export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: 'Todo App',
    description: 'Todo application for practicing Next.js',
};

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<p className="text-yellow-400">Loading...</p>}>
                 <TodoList />
        </Suspense>
    );
}

Hope it will solve the issue.
